# Dartlang: Create table rows with different number of radio buttons

Tags: radio-button, dart, dart-html

I'm new to web programming and until now i was just creating table with rows which have only one radio button or checkbox etc... But now i have to create a table with rows containing different number of radio buttons. My table has only 2 columns. First column will contain indicator names of rows. Second column will contain radio buttons. So how can i create a cell containing multiple radio buttons. Some row would have 10 or more radio buttons so no one would want to append 10 radio buttons one after another, right?

Edit: I created it like this:

```dart
 List anketScoreList = [{'id': 'university','text': 'University Score'}, 
                        {'id': 'gpa', 'text': 'GPA Score'}, 
                        {'id': 'language', 'text': 'Language Score'},
                        {'id': 'success', 'text': 'Success Score'}, 
                        {'id': 'fabric', 'text': 'Fabric Score'}, 
                        {'id': 'essay', 'text': 'Essay Score'}];
 //Radio values
 List score3 = ["1", "1.5", "2"];
 List score5 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
 List score10 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

 //creating table body
 anketScoreList.forEach((a) {
   index += 1;
   tbody.append(new Element.tr()
       ..append(new TableCellElement()..text = index.toString())
       ..append(new TableCellElement()..append(new LabelElement()
       ..text = a['text']
       ..setAttribute('for', a['id'])))
       ..append(createRadioButtons(a)));
 });

 Element createRadioButtons(metadata){
   List m;
   if(metadata['id'] == "university"){
       m = score3;
     } else if(metadata['id'] == "gpa" || metadata['id'] == "language" || 
               metadata['id'] == "essay"){
       m = score5;
     } else if(metadata['id'] == "success" || metadata['id'] == "fabric"){
       m = score10;
     }

 var td = new TableCellElement();
 m.forEach((score){
   td.append(new InputElement()
   ..type = "radio"
   ..id = metadata['id']
   ..value = score
   ..name = metadata['id']
   ..classes.add("radio")
   ..onSelect.listen((e){
  })
  );
});
return td;
}
```

So is there any easier way to do this? Specially for the lists that i created, assuming there will be other values like genders, types etc... ? 
In addition i have another little question. I tried onSelect, onClick on my radio input element but it didn't work. I was just testing with something like x = x + 10 so just removed that code from my onSelect.listen function.

Comment: To me its totally unclear what you are asking for. What's your problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer There is roughly 75.4% chance that he asks(in a highly cryptic way) how to efficiently inject collection of a new elements with a varying size  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a map for the scores:

```dart
Map scores = {
  'university': score3,
  'gpa':, score5,
  'language: score5,
  'essay: score5,
  'success': score10,
  'fabric': score10
};
```

your `createRadioButtons` could the be simplified to

```dart
Element createRadioButtons(metadata){

  // or use a switch
  //
  // List m;
  // switch(metadata['id']) {
  //   case 'university': 
  //     m = score3;
  //     break;
  //   case 'gpa':
  //   case 'language':
  //   case 'essay':
  //     m = score5;
  //     break;
  //   case 'success':
  //   case 'fabric':
  //     m = score10;
  //     break;
  // }    

  var td = new TableCellElement();

  //m.forEach((score) {

  scores[metadata['id']].forEach((score){
    td.append(new InputElement()
        ..type = "radio"
        ..id = metadata['id']
        ..value = score
        ..name = metadata['id']
        ..classes.add("radio")
        ..onSelect.listen((e){

        })
    );
  });
  return td;
}
```

For change notification you can use `onClick` or `onChange`
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/onclick-onchange.php

Comment: Thanks. I guess creating Map is much better in my case :D. For onClick  I had a little mistake in my code, so I fixed it and it's working now :)

Comment: The Map has the advantage that you can easily build/manipulate it at runtime.

Comment: @C0iL In a real world application you will get this data from server. For example, in JSON format (map of key/value pairs). Dart List is more similar to vectors(arrays) then to classic Lists, because it has random access. If you want something specialized for this kind of tasks(for practice) then you can use Queue from dart:collection.